# Why won't my PS4 Pro work with any 4K HDMI switch?

Tags: ps4, hdmi

I have a 4K monitor, a PS4 Pro, and a laptop. I want to be able to quickly switch between the PS4 Pro and the laptop by flipping a switch.

I've tried two different 4K HDMI switches from Amazon ([1](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005SP6ARO), [2](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0734SYLJL)). Both of them work with the laptop (at 4K) but **neither** of them work with the PS4 Pro.

NB. The PS4 Pro works fine when plugged *directly* into the 4K monitor, just not when used via either switch. So the issue is not the PS4. I have tried all combinations of cables and tried all the different input ports on both switches. The result is always the same.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like you need a mechanical switch for your splitter, or your switches don't have HDCP, I quote description from your second switch :

> ULTRA HD RESOLUTION - This 4K HDMI Switch supports resolution up to 4K@30Hz, 1080p 3D@60Hz, 1080p Full HD@120Hz. HDMI version 1.4 and backwards compatible (NOTE: It CAN'T compatible with HDCP 2.2)

The ps4 pro doesn't run on 4K@30Hz, & it needs HDCP... AND you want HDMI 2.0 minimum.

So something akin to [this](https://sewelldirect.com/ibis-4k-hdmi-switch-box-2x1-white) might be your solution
(checkout the product description for more info).

Good luck !